# select2, how to change before show

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using select2 to build my combo.

some elements are disabled, but I want to show them bold but with aria-required="false"

```
var data= [{
     id="1",
     value = "first",
     disabled:true
},{
     id="2",
     value = "second",
     disabled:false
},

];
function formatResult(node) {
  if(node.disabled){
    var $result = $('<span><strong>' + node.text + '</strong></span>');
  } else {
    var $result = $('<span>' + node.text + '</span>');
  }
  return $result;
}

$("#myCombo").select2({
  placeholder: 'Seleccione una opción',
  width: "350px",
  data: data,
  formatSelection: function(item) {
    return item.text
  },
  formatResult: function(item) {
    return item.text
  },
  templateResult: formatResult
});
```

};

that works, but the li :

```
<li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-disabled="true">
        <span style="padding-left:20px;"><strong>first</strong></span>
</li>
```

when it's opened, with debugger, if I execute:

```
$('.select2-results__option').attr('aria-disabled',false);
```

it works as I want, but I'm not able to do this programatically, it seems there is not exists a beforeShow function, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can achieve this with a timeout.

```
$("#myCombo").select2({
  placeholder: 'Seleccione una opción',
  width: "350px",
  data: data,
  formatSelection: function(item) {
    return item.text
  },
  formatResult: function(item) {
    return item.text
  },
  templateResult: formatResult
});
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.select2-results__option').attr('aria-disabled',false);
});
```

Comment: it works, but I should put the setTimeout in my formatResult function, because it is called everytime I click the select